# Integrate Stack Overflow with Vim

Tags: firefox, vim

I have started doing review tasks in here lately (editing first posts/late answers etc.).

- At first I was trying to edit from Firefox itself
- and then I started copying to Vim and do the formatting there
- shortly I discovered [it's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) plugin for Firefox to edit multi-line text fields

So now I'm trying to find the next step which will eliminate all those mouse clicks(edit/submit etc.) to do the job solely on Vim. The current interface in Firefox (giving you the next first post with one click) seems quite capable to be integrated into Vim itself so I was wondering if/how it is possible to achieve this?

If not, what are some good practices you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially due to the increasingly rich user interfaces (and the underlying JavaScript requirement) of modern web applications like Stack Overflow, I would recommend against moving out of the browser, especially because implementing a Vim-based client (though possible with tools like *curl*, *wget*, or even available libraries like [webapi.vim](https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim)) is a lot of effort.

I find it already quite efficient to use your mentioned Firefox add-on (I've since moved to *Pentadactyl*, a *Vimperator* fork), and a separate GVIM instance, especially if you streamline this. I've described in a [blog post](http://ingo-karkat.de/blog/2012/05/22/Pentadactyl%20set%20filetype%20in%20external%20Vim%20editor%20based%20on%20URL.html) how to automatically set the `markdown` filetype for Stack Overflow text areas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's one approach:

1. Install [Vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org/), the awesom Vim-like plugin for Firefox
2. Add the following to ~/.vimperatorrc

   autocmd LocationChange .* :set editor="xterm -x vim"

Vim editor in a browser controlled by vim keypresses, no mouse necessary.  Win.  (Substite your xterm of choice, btw)

Another way to do it is to switch to the terminal and use w3m.  Easy enough to configure that to use vim as the editor.  Not so easy to use stackoverflow without JavaScript, though.

Comment: I had once used `vimperator` and "numbering all links in the page" wasn't really convenient to me. I was more hoping something like `:FetchNewPost()` or `:UpdateCurrentPost()` functions from vim.

Answer (score 0):

I just started trying out w3m to browse in the terminal. You can change all the keybindings to be vim-like (for web-specific things, I copied the bindings in Vimium), and edit text fields on the sites using vim directly. I've only been using it a day, and I don't know how to deal with the 'are you a robot' checks yet... but it seems nice for closing the gap between coding in vim, and googling + copy and pasting stuff back into vim.

I have it setup so when I press v in w3m it opens the page in vim, and I set vim up to immediately save the file as /tmp/w3m_scratch and exit back to w3m. Then I go to an instance of vim where I'm coding, and use another mapping that toggles a horizontal split with the /tmp/w3m_scratch file (i.e. the webpage I was interested in). This lets me quickly get all the info on a page into the same vim instance that I'm coding in, and can use all the power of vim to integrate the text from stackoverflow (or some other site) into my work:

```
function! WriteW3MToScratch()
    " only if the file matches this highly specific reg exp will we do anything
    "(e.g. a file that looks like: .w3m/w3mtmp7352-3)
    if match(@%, "\.w3m/w3mtmp\\d\\+-\\d") != -1
        :silent! wq! /tmp/w3m_scratch
    endif
endfunction

function! ToggleW3M()
    if bufexists("/tmp/w3m_scratch")
        :bwipe! /tmp/w3m_scratch
    else
        :silent! split /tmp/w3m_scratch
    endif
endfunction

" anytime we read in a buffer, if it came from w3m then write to scratch
autocmd BufReadPost * :call WriteW3MToScratch()

" open/close horizontal split containing w3m_scratch
nnoremap <leader>w :call ToggleW3M()<cr>
```

I used the keymap file on [this git repo](https://github.com/felipesaa/A-vim-like-firefox-like-configuration-for-w3m) as a base, here's what I have so far. I have to say it does feel very vim-like with these settings.

```
# w3m keymap file with Vim key bindings
# by Felipe Saa (https://github.com/felipesaa/A-vim-like-firefox-like-configuration-for-w3m)
# adapted by Matthew Bennett
#
# Ctrl      : C-, ^
# Escape    : ESC-, M-, ^[
# Space     : SPC, ' '
# Tab       : TAB, ^i, ^I
# Shift+Tab : ^[[Z
# Delete    : DEL, ^?
# Up        : UP, ^[[A
# Down      : DOWN, ^[[B
# Right     : RIGHT, ^[[C
# Left      : LEFT, ^[[D
# Re Pag    : M-[5~
# Av Pag    : M-[6~
# Enter     : C-j  RET(pendant confirm)

#-custom map commands..........................................................
# switch the color of links for light/dark colourscheme
keymap  SPCd    COMMAND         "SET_OPTION  anchor_color=yellow"
keymap  SPCl    COMMAND         "SET_OPTION  anchor_color=blue"
# skip past all the cruft on the stack sites to where the question is asked
keymap  st      COMMAND         "WHEREIS Ask\ Question;  CENTER_V;  NEXT_HALF_PAGE"

#-scrolling....................................................................
keymap  C-y     DOWN
keymap  C-e     UP
keymap  gg      BEGIN
keymap  G       END
keymap  C-d     NEXT_HALF_PAGE
keymap  C-u     PREV_HALF_PAGE
keymap  C-f     COMMAND         "NEXT_HALF_PAGE;  NEXT_HALF_PAGE"
keymap  C-b     COMMAND         "PREV_HALF_PAGE;  PREV_HALF_PAGE"
keymap  zz      CENTER_V
keymap  zt      COMMAND         "CENTER_V;        NEXT_HALF_PAGE"
keymap  zb      COMMAND         "CENTER_V;        PREV_HALF_PAGE"

#-cursor.......................................................................
keymap  l       MOVE_RIGHT1
keymap  h       MOVE_LEFT1
keymap  j       MOVE_DOWN1
keymap  k       MOVE_UP1
keymap  0       LINE_BEGIN
keymap  $       LINE_END
keymap  w       NEXT_WORD
keymap  b       PREV_WORD
keymap  C-o     UNDO            # Undo cursor movement.
# keymap  C-i  REDO             # Undo undone cursor movement (confused with TAB)

#-tab..........................................................................
# Close current tab and save it to be able to restore it.
keymap  x       COMMAND         "EXTERN 'echo %s >> ~/.w3m/RestoreTab.txt' ; CLOSE_TAB"

# new search in new tab (drops right into google search)
keymap  o       COMMAND         "GOTO https://google.com; GOTO_LINE 6; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"

# new search (drops right into google search)
keymap O        COMMAND         "TAB_GOTO https://google.com; GOTO_LINE 6; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"

keymap J        PREV_TAB        # Change focus to right tab
keymap K        NEXT_TAB        # Change focus to left tab
keymap gJ       TAB_LEFT        # Move tab to the left
keymap gK       TAB_RIGHT       # Move tab to the right
keymap yt       NEW_TAB         # Duplicate current tab
keymap gt       TAB_MENU        # Tab menu
keymap :t       TAB_MENU        # Tab menu
# keymap X        TAB_GOTO        /usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin/restore_tab.cgi # Restore last closed tab

#-url operations...............................................................
keymap f        GOTO_LINK       # Follow link in current tab
keymap gf       TAB_LINK        # Follow link in a new foreground tab
keymap F        COMMAND         "TAB_LINK; PREV_TAB" # follow link under cursor in new background tab
keymap gF       MOVE_LIST_MENU  # link list --> move cursor to link
keymap r        RELOAD          # Reload current page.

#-link navigation..............................................................
keymap [        NEXT_LEFT_UP
keymap ]        NEXT_RIGHT_DOWN

#-history navigation...........................................................
keymap L        NEXT            # Go forward in history
keymap H        PREV            # Go back in history
keymap :b       SELECT_MENU     # Recent pages
keymap :B       HISTORY         # Show history

#-bookmarks....................................................................
# keymap C-d      ADD_BOOKMARK  # Add current page to bookmarks
# keymap gb       VIEW_BOOKMARK # Show bookmarks
# keymap :b       VIEW_BOOKMARK # Show bookmarks

#-search.......................................................................
keymap /        ISEARCH         # Enter find mode
keymap ?        ISEARCH_BACK    # Enter find mode backwards (incremental)
keymap n        SEARCH_NEXT     # Find next
keymap N        SEARCH_PREV     # Find previous

#-commands.....................................................................
keymap !        COMMAND         
keymap |        PIPE_BUF        # Send rendered document to pipe

keymap :h       HELP            # View help
keymap :o       OPTIONS         # Option setting panel
keymap :q       QUIT            # Quit w3m with confirmation (q alone works too)
keymap ZZ       EXIT            # Quit w3m without confirmation.

# Reload configuration files.
keymap :s       REINIT

#-info.........................................................................
keymap gC-g     INFO            # current page info
keymap C-g      LINE_INFO       # line under cursor info

#-miscellaneous................................................................
keymap v        EDIT_SCREEN     # Edit current rendered document with sensible-editor

#-unused url operations.......................................................
# keymap        PEEK                        # Show current page url.
# Focus in address bar.
# keymap ef    PEEK_LINK                    # Show link under cursor.
# Execute external browser = open current link in $BROWSER
# tip: number(2-9) + external browser shortcut(M-o) executes executes the
# external browser command linked to the prefix number.
# See "External Program Settings" in "Option Setting Panel"(OPTIONS)
# Open current link with external browser = sensible browser
# keymap M-o   EXTERN
# copy current url and remove newline at the end.
# keymap yy    EXTERN     copy_url.sh
# keymap yy       EXTERN     "echo -n %s | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
# keymap yy       EXTERN     "echo -n %s | xsel -b"
# open link under cursor with external browser = sensible browser
# keymap M-p   EXTERN_LINK
# Copy link under cursor, It does not copy images urls
# keymap yf       EXTERN_LINK 'env printf %s "$0" | xsel -b'
# keymap yf    EXTERN_LINK  copy_url.sh
# follow link in clipboard in the current tab.
# keymap p   GOTO       /usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin/goto_clipboard.cgi
# follow link in clipboard in new foreground tab.
# keymap P     TAB_GOTO /usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin/goto_clipboard.cgi

#-.............................................................................
```